# How do I use methods with optional data

Tags: java

I have created a class called `Person` which uses `Optional<LocalDate>` to store a person's birthday as a field. I have a method called `timeToNextBirthday` which computes the interval between the time of calling and the next birthday. The problem I'm having is that since birthday is optional, the method sometimes has nothing it can return. I don't know if I should throw an exception or just return some default object. I also considered making the return type optional and returning an empty optional if the birthday is unknown. This is a snippet of my code so far, using the exception option.

```
public class Person {
    private Optional<LocalDate> dateOfBirth;

    public Period timeToNextBirthday() throws NoSuchElementException {
        if(!dateOfBirth.isPresent()) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Birthday is unknown");
        }

        LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();

        // Assume this year's birthday has not passed and set next birthday to this year
        LocalDate nextBirthday = dateOfBirth.get().withYear(currentDate.getYear());

        // Add a year to nextBirthday if this year's birthday has already passed or is today
        if (currentDate.isAfter(nextBirthday) || currentDate.equals(nextBirthday)) {
            nextBirthday = nextBirthday.plusYears(1);
        }

        return Period.between(currentDate, nextBirthday);
    }

}
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Generally speaking you should return either `null` or an "empty" object in such situations. "Empty" of course depends on your object, but it is usually safer than returning `null`.

Comment: What is wrong if you have simple date field for Dob in class person ?

Comment: I think all of your suggestions are suitable solutions for that problem, you have to decide how your API should work... just describe the behavior in a java-doc! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this: Changing the method's return type to `Optional<Period>` would make it very clear to the user of this method that it may not result in an usable `Period` due to `dateOfBirth` being optional and the user space code must be made to accomodate for this fact.

This sort of type carry-over is just fine if you don't want to throw exceptions (*like you currently do*) as it allows you as an API designer to assist the user of your code to cover all bases in a secure, `null` safe and self documenting way. Of course writing a bit of javadoc explaining why the return type is wrapped in `Optional` won't hurt either :)